# USDZ Model in Threejs and Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I have a usdz model file of Laidar data that I want to view in my web browser. I have gone through every possible documentation but resources are limited and I am not able to make any meaningful progress to view it using Reactjs and Threejs. If someone can share an implementation or guide I would be grateful!

Comment: you can look at this npm package https://github.com/ponahoum/three-usdz-loader

Comment: There is a UDSZ loader in the `three` npm package: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_usdz. I would start with that before using a third-party library.